# Sorting Text alphabetically using last word before comma

Tags: notepad++, sorting

I'm currently ordered to sort a list with ~250 entries alphabetically. Problem is: Not using the first word(s), or a specific column, but using the last term before the first comma:

```
[li]title surname1 name1, occupation, city[/li
][li]title surname2 name3, occupation, city[/li
][li]title surname3 name3, occupation, city[/li]
```

I'm currently trying to not do this manually. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? You can answer your own question if so

Answer (score 1):

Save your data to a text file and open it in MS Excel or LibreOffice Calc (free) as "comma delimited", but in your case change the delimiter to space. You can then sort and filter on any column you want.

Excel Import Wizard looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Nice idea, but many items have multiple titles, surnames or names, resulting in very different columns for the last names.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the structure was consistent. You can import to Excel as comma delimited and then split the first column using an Excel function, then sort on the extracted "last name".

Comment: A little clunky, but it's working for me

Comment: You can use Notepad++'s Find / Replace (Ctrl + H) and if needed use the Extended / Regular expression to change your delimiter (space) to tab (\t or copy/paste to clipboard before bringing up the Replace dialog) then you can just copy/paste to Excel - no need to save text file and import etc. Saves a step anyway!